# Why I am not getting the Coverage with SonarQube?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, sonarqube, mocha.js, sonarscanner

I am running a Jenkin's job to run the test cases with `Mocha` and to run `sonar-scanner` on a project with AngularJS and Node. In SonarQube, I am not getting the coverage result but I am getting the other results. And I have included `lcov.info` file path as well. And below are the properties and the values that I have given to Sonar.

```
sonar.projectKey=my:project
sonar.projectName=my
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=lib
sonar.tests=test
sonar.language=js
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
```

Can anyone please help me to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was using an older version of Sonar Qube. So, it is getting the coverage with `sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath`, not with  `sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths`.